# Pandas merge not working

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have 2 data frames:
 transp_merged.head()

```
  type_str   agb  GRID
0     GRID  1457  1457
0   S100D0     6  1457
0   S100D1  1079  1457
0   S100D2  1718  1457
0   S100D3  1970  1457
```

and 
step1_merge.head()

```
   VALUE  COUNT  GRID   mukey   ksat    type type_str
0      2  14897  1476  398864  12.88   s67d3    S67D3
1     10   5667  1477  398864  12.88   s67d3    S67D3
2    976  21013  1425  398864  12.88   s67d3    S67D3
3   1086   6704  1424  398864  12.88   s67d3    S67D3
4   2431    272  1426  398864  12.88   s67d3    S67D3
```

However, when I try to merge the two using:

```
 result = pandas.merge(step1_merge,transp_merged,on=[u'type_str','GRID'])
```

the resulting dataframe is empty. However, when I check manually in excel, there should be data in result. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show part of the dataframe whith rows that should merge? Because in the `.head()` you show now there aren't any.

Comment: Do you have common values for your columns to be merged? If not then the default type of merge is 'inner' and so this could explain why you have no rows, if you want to combine all data from both then do `result = pandas.merge(step1_merge,transp_merged,on=[u'type_str','GRID'], how='outer')`

Comment: I am having a similar problem. There are several points that do not join/merge. However, when searched for in excel they are found.